# Is there a single word that means "To commit treason"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word I can use in place of 'committing treason' in the sentence

> "The corporal was on trial for **committing treason**."

so the sentence reads

> "The corporal was on trial for _____ing"

Comment: Welcome to SE! Thank you for including a sample sentence. What research have you done? What words have you tried and rejected?

Comment: You can try using a synonym such as "mutiny", "revolt", "rebel", but there's probably nothing that carries the precise same legal implications.

Comment: Any normal person would simply use the noun ***treason*** in your context (***committing*** is completely redundant). If you're determined to use an alternative, and you don't mind sounding pretentious, consider [***treasonry***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205365) (*obsolete, rare*, according to the full OED).

Comment: The related verb is "to betray," but it is transitive, so you cannot say "the corporal was on trial for betraying."  Furthermore, _treason_ is far more specific than _betray_ nowadays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treason is a defined legal concept, so has a definite meaning. There's no verb form of treason. Use

> The corporal was on trial for treason.

Comment: "Defined legal concept" doesn't entail "there's no verb form," unless you can explain why.

Comment: @AzorAhai I don't think he was making an implication, just stating independent facts.

Answer (score 2):

The verb is the same as the noun - 'treason'. But the verb form is stated by the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205356?rskey=opCZvM&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) to be 'rare'.

> 13..   K. Alis. 723   Thy fadir hastow tresond here!
>   c1330   R. Mannyng Chron. (1810) 105   Þei wer fulle wele knowen, þat wild haf tresond him.
>   c1374   Chaucer Troilus & Criseyde iv. 410 (438)   To traysen [v.r. trassen] a wight þat trewe is vn-to me.
>   1890   L. Lewis Proving of Gennad xv. 104   Ere morning, thou shalt know who **treasons** thee.
>   (Hide quotations)

Answer (score -3):

No verb springs to mind, but the sentiment is captured by **treachery**.

> **treachery** noun
>
> 1 : violation of allegiance or of faith and confidence : treason
>
> 2 : an act of perfidy or treason
>
> - Marriam-Webster

So the sentence would read: "The corporal was on trial for **treachery**".

Note: As others have pointed out, certain words have different and specific meanings in law, so it depends whether you are describing the actual crime they are being tried for, or simply a general statement about its nature.

Comment: Treachery describes behavior or character. Treason is a criminal offense. No one is on trial for treachery.

Comment: It is quite literally an act of treason. Much as one could be on trial for blowing up a house, and charged with arson, one may on trial for treachery and charged with treason.

Comment: I don't think anyone would say "The corporal was on trial for killing."

Comment: One could say "The corporal was on trial for killing his commanding officer", but since "treachery" doesn't really have the same construction so it is fine to leave as is.

Comment: Yes, and you could say "The corporal was on trial for betraying his country". But that's not a single word, and treachery is not a verb, so neither answer the question.

Comment: That is needlessly verbose, and as the other answer mentions, there is no verb, so we are looking for alternatives that fit the meaning, of which treachery is one.

Comment: But OP asks for a verb, while *treachery* is a noun. If OP wanted to use a noun they could just use *treason*.